# Set the name of an input control in a jrxml file. Is it possible?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I'd like to set the name of an input control in the jrxml file where it is defined; is that possible?

I know how to set the name of the input control via the Repository Explorer in Jaspersoft Studio, and I know how to set the name of an input control via the Jaspersoft Server.

However, I'd like to set the name of an input control in the jrxml file so that it will be set automatically upon being published to the server. Is there a property to use, similar to the following:

```
<parameter name="status_date_minimum" class="java.sql.Date">
  <property name="some.property.key" vhalue="Minimum Status Date"/>
  <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[java.sql.Date.valueOf(java.time.LocalDate.now().minusYears(10).withMonth(1).withDayOfMonth(1))]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

Comment: What is a reason to pass name of input control to report (as parameter?)? Looks strange

Comment: I simply want to indicate the name of the control in the jrxml, rather than set it manually though the interface; it's more consistent and requires less effort.

Comment: Yes, that is obviously possible (if I understand your question correctly). This detail in given in a .xml file (the metadata file of a report unit) and not the jrxml. You can export your existing report and have a look to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by @Siddharth in comments and suggested to me by a co-worker, there is a way to specify the label for the control outside of the user interface.

JasperReports Server associates each report with an XML file that it appears to create around the time it publishes your report to the server. The XML file contains, among other information, the labels for any input controls.

For an example of the XML file, first publish your report to a location on JasperReports Server. For the purpose of this example, the report file name is `report.jrxml` and the location is `path/to/your`; JasperReports Server appears to publish your report to `path/to/your/report/Main jrxml` (per JasperSoft Studio Repository Explorer) or `path/to/your/report` (per JasperReports Server Web UI).

Second, export your report from JasperReports Server ([via the Web UI](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-administration-guide/v550/import-and-export-through-web-ui) or [via the command line](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-administration-guide/v550/import-and-export-through-command-line)); JasperReports Server will produce a zip file with the following content:

```
/index.xml
/resources/path/.folder.xml
/resources/path/to/.folder.xml
/resources/path/to/your/.folder.xml
/resources/path/to/your/report.xml
/resources/path/to/your/report_files/main_jrxml.data
```

`main_jrxml.data` contains the data from `report.jrxml`; `report.xml` contains the labels for any input controls. The content of `report.xml` may be similar to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<reportUnit exportedWithPermissions="true">
    <folder>/resources/path/to/your</folder>
    <name>report</name>
    <version>2</version>
    <label>report</label>
    <description></description>
    <creationDate>2018-03-21T18:12:41.759-04:00</creationDate>
    <updateDate>2018-03-21T18:48:35.602-04:00</updateDate>
    <mainReport>
        <localResource
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                exportedWithPermissions="false" dataFile="main_jrxml.data" xsi:type="fileResource">
            <folder>/resources/path/to/your/report_files</folder>
            <name>main_jrxml</name>
            <version>4</version>
            <label>Main jrxml</label>
            <creationDate>2018-03-21T18:12:41.759-04:00</creationDate>
            <updateDate>2018-03-21T18:48:35.410-04:00</updateDate>
            <fileType>jrxml</fileType>
        </localResource>
    </mainReport>
    <inputControl>
        <localResource
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                exportedWithPermissions="false" xsi:type="inputControl">
            <folder>/resources/path/to/your/report_files</folder>
            <name>status_date_minimum</name>
            <version>1</version>
            <label>status_date_minimum</label>
            <creationDate>2018-03-21T18:48:35.602-04:00</creationDate>
            <updateDate>2018-03-21T18:48:35.602-04:00</updateDate>
            <type>2</type>
            <mandatory>false</mandatory>
            <readOnly>false</readOnly>
            <visible>true</visible>
            <dataType>
                <localResource exportedWithPermissions="false" xsi:type="dataType">
                    <folder>/resources/path/to/your/report_files/status_date_minimum_files</folder>
                    <name>myDatatype</name>
                    <version>0</version>
                    <label>myDatatype</label>
                    <creationDate>2018-03-21T18:48:35.602-04:00</creationDate>
                    <updateDate>2018-03-21T18:48:35.602-04:00</updateDate>
                    <type>3</type>
                    <strictMin>false</strictMin>
                    <strictMax>false</strictMax>
                </localResource>
            </dataType>
        </localResource>
    </inputControl>
    <inputControl>
        <localResource
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                exportedWithPermissions="false" xsi:type="inputControl">
            <folder>/resources/path/to/your/report_files</folder>
            <name>status_date_maximum</name>
            <version>1</version>
            <label>status_date_maximum</label>
            <creationDate>2018-03-21T18:48:35.602-04:00</creationDate>
            <updateDate>2018-03-21T18:48:35.602-04:00</updateDate>
            <type>2</type>
            <mandatory>false</mandatory>
            <readOnly>false</readOnly>
            <visible>true</visible>
            <dataType>
                <localResource exportedWithPermissions="false" xsi:type="dataType">
                    <folder>/resources/path/to/your/report_files/status_date_maximum_files</folder>
                    <name>myDatatype</name>
                    <version>0</version>
                    <label>myDatatype</label>
                    <creationDate>2018-03-21T18:48:35.602-04:00</creationDate>
                    <updateDate>2018-03-21T18:48:35.602-04:00</updateDate>
                    <type>3</type>
                    <strictMin>false</strictMin>
                    <strictMax>false</strictMax>
                </localResource>
            </dataType>
        </localResource>
    </inputControl>
    <alwaysPromptControls>true</alwaysPromptControls>
    <controlsLayout>1</controlsLayout>
</reportUnit>
```

You may edit the content of the `reportUnit/inputControl/localResource/label` element to change the name of the label.

Once edited, you may import the data into the JasperReports Server. If you import through the command line, I recommend importing the directory, not the zip file - it appears that the command line import is picky about the zip format. Also, if you import through the command line, you must restart the JasperReports Server before you may run your changed report.